# Como fazer o return Ok<object> receber vários argumentos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, api

Boa tarde galera, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida com vocês, estou criando um método dentro uma webapi em asp.net mvc para receber alguns dados do lançamento de uma visita domiciliar, mas estou tendo um erro no **return Ok < object >**, que me fala que o método **Ok< object >** não pode receber mais de 1 argumento, como sou novato em programação então acontece alguns erros que por enquanto eu não consigo resolver, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Boa tarde a todos!!

```
//CAPTURAR VISITAS
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetVisitas/{grupoId}/{userId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetVisitas(int grupoId, int userId)
    {


        var visita_periodica = false;
        var cadastro_atualizacao = false;
        var consulta = false;
        var exame = false;
        var vacina = false;
        var gestante = false;
        var recemNascido = false;
        var desnutricao = false;
        var deficiencia = false;
        var hipertenso = false;
        var diabetes = false;
        var asma = false;
        var acamado = false;
        var tuberculose = false;
        var cancer = false;
        var imovelComFoco = false;
        var acaoMecanico = false;
        var realizada = false;
        var recusada = false;
        var ausente = false;

        var visitas = db.GruposDetalhes.Where(gd => gd.GrupoId == grupoId && gd.UserId == userId).ToList();

        foreach (var visita in visitas)
        {
            foreach (var visita2 in visita.Visitas)
            {
                visita_periodica = visita2.Visita_periodica;
                cadastro_atualizacao = visita2.Cadastro_atualizacao;
                consulta = visita2.Consulta;
                exame = visita2.Exame;
                vacina = visita2.Vacina;
                gestante = visita2.Gestante;
                recemNascido = visita2.RecemNascido;
                desnutricao = visita2.Desnutricao;
                deficiencia = visita2.Deficiencia;
                hipertenso = visita2.Hipertenso;
                diabetes = visita2.Diabetes;
                asma = visita2.Asma;
                acamado = visita2.Acamado;
                tuberculose = visita2.Tuberculose;
                cancer = visita2.Cancer;
                imovelComFoco = visita2.ImovelComFoco;
                acaoMecanico = visita2.AcaoMecanico;
                realizada = visita2.Realizada;
                recusada = visita2.Recusada;
                ausente = visita2.Ausente;
            }
        }

        return Ok<object>(
            new { Visitas = visita_periodica },
            new { Visitas = cadastro_atualizacao },
            new { Visitas = consulta },
            new { Visitas = exame },
            new { Visitas = vacina },
            new { Visitas = gestante },
            new { Visitas = recemNascido },
            new { Visitas = desnutricao },
            new { Visitas = deficiencia },
            new { Visitas = hipertenso },
            new { Visitas = diabetes },
            new { Visitas = asma },
            new { Visitas = acamado },
            new { Visitas = tuberculose },
            new { Visitas = cancer },
            new { Visitas = imovelComFoco },
            new { Visitas = acaoMecanico },
            new { Visitas = realizada },
            new { Visitas = recusada },
            new { Visitas = ausente });
    }
```

//METODO ORIGINAL DO TUTORIAL QUE ESTOU SEGUINDO

```
//CAPTURAR NOTAAS
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetNotas/{grupoId}/{userId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetNotas(int grupoId, int userId)
    {
        var notaDef = 0.0;
        var notas = db.GruposDetalhes.Where(gd => gd.GrupoId == grupoId && gd.UserId == userId).ToList();
        foreach(var nota in notas)
        {
            foreach(var nota2 in nota.Notas)
            {
                notaDef += nota2.Percentual + nota2.Nota;
            }
        }
        return Ok<object>(new { Notas = notaDef});               
    }
```

Comment: vc pode criar o objeto antes abribuindo a uma variável e simplesmente retornar `return Ok(variavel)`

Answer (score 1):

Você não está retornando um objeto, mas sim uma coleção... E o método `Ok()` não pode receber um argumento genérico de tipo.

Abaixo segue uma alternativa, longe de ser a forma mais elegante...

```
return Ok( new List<object>{
               new { Visitas = visita_periodica },
               new { Visitas = cadastro_atualizacao },
               new { Visitas = consulta },
               new { Visitas = exame },
               new { Visitas = vacina },
               // ...
           });
```

Comment: Mt obrigado Leandro Angelo, vou tentar implementar dessa forma !!

Comment: @Ricardo Agora me explique o que de fato você está tentando fazer, porque o resto do seu código e o retorno que vai obter não fazem muito sentido...

Comment: Então Leandro, na vdd pelo tutorial que estou seguindo para implementar no meu projeto está de uma forma um pouco diferente, pois foi criado para fazer um calculo e então eu tentei implementar no meu caso, porém no meu caso eu nao vou fazer calculo, somente vou retornar os dados gravados previamente da visita, por isso dos 2 laços for, mas sei que no meu caso não deveria ser daquela forma mas como sou iniciante então eu nao tenho o conhecimento suficiente para mudar o método, vou colocar o metodo de como está no tutorial pra vc entender certinho.